# Unable to resolve spring-webmvc-5.0.0.M5 dependency in spring-mvc project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a *spring-mvc* project. In my *pom* file following dependency was added previously:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.M5</version>
</dependency>
```

And repository is:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Alfresco Public Repository</id>
        <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I deleted *repository* folder under *.m2*. After that I was getting following error when I try to build the project(**mvn clean install**):

> The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.0.M5: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.0.M5 in https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Alfresco Public Repository has elapsed or updates are forced

I have added new repository in my *pom*:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Alfresco Public Repository</id>
        <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.spring.milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Now I am getting following error:

> Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.0.M5: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.0.M5: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-webmvc:pom:5.0.0.M5 from/to repository.spring.milestone (http://repo.spring.io/milestone): Access denied to: http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.0.0.M5/spring-webmvc-5.0.0.M5.pom

From browser I can see [spring-webmvc-5.0.0.M5.pom](https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.0.0.M5/spring-webmvc-5.0.0.M5.pom).

1. Why I am getting **"Access denied"**?
2. What is the solution of this problem?

> **Note:** I am unable to update the version **5.0.0.M5** to **5.0.0.RELEASE**

Comment: Did you try to change the Spring Milestone Repository to https? Maybe something isn't working with the redirect from http to https.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian. You are right. It's working fine now.

Comment: Why on earth are you using such an old version and a milestone even? Use one of the final releases not an intermediate non-final release. Those should come from maven central.

Comment: It's a management decision my friend @M.Deinum, I am sitting on the fence and working on legacy code :)

Comment: Management isn't the right place to make those decisions. Never use a milestone (beta release of software) in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [@Sebastian's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631510/unable-to-resolve-spring-webmvc-5-0-0-m5-dependency-in-spring-mvc-project?noredirect=1#comment107302253_60631510), I have changed **http** to **https** at Spring Milestone Repository:

```
<repository>
    <id>repository.spring.milestone</id>
    <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
</repository>
```

It's working fine now. Thanks [@Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266467/sebastian)